# Sql - Convert rows to cloums

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot, pivot-table

I am new to sql Pivot. I have table called "devices" with content like this.

```
+------------------------------+------------------
| device_id    | serial_number | imei            |
+------------------------------+------------------
| A1yLCM4xe9cn | PIE7JHgo8rLwG | 767523638130820 |
| A1yLCM4xe9cn | PIE7JHgo8rLwG | 100509490452499 |
| OJndw9C5X5I4 | 8lZ0YkPHjv5qA | 893567359155395 |
| OJndw9C5X5I4 | 8lZ0YkPHjv5qA | 336707619575525 |
| RIaKTBPEFQlc | CYGKQLSluJIRq | 269331663151346 |
```

I am trying to get a select query like this

```
+------------------------------+----------------------------------
| device_id    | serial_number | imei1           | imei2         |
+------------------------------+----------------------------------
| A1yLCM4xe9cn | PIE7JHgo8rLwG | 767523638130820 | 100509490452499
| OJndw9C5X5I4 | 8lZ0YkPHjv5qA | 893567359155395 | 336707619575525
| RIaKTBPEFQlc | CYGKQLSluJIRq | 269331663151346 | NULL
```

I was able to get for hard coded values. Would it be possible to  dynamically convert rows to columns?

Comment: Is there some way to order the semi-duplicate records?

Comment: Always two imei values per device_id/serieal_no?

Comment: Not always. There can be only one imei also. @jarlh

Comment: Can't you add that to your sample data, and adjust the expected result?

Comment: Is there any possibility to more then 2 imei no? or max 2 imei ?

Comment: Sample data should be updated .Thanks. @jarlh

Comment: There are only max 2 imei's. @SharadPatel

Comment: What if the same imei value twice, for a device_id/serieal_no?

Comment: They would go under imei1 and Imei2. @jarlh

Comment: Added a query that takes care of two same or different imei values, as well as only one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are always two imei values per device_id/serieal_no:

```
select device_id, serial_number, min(imei) as imei1, max(imei) as imei2
from tablename
group by device_id, serial_number
```

If there are one or two imei values per device_id/serieal_no:

```
select device_id, serial_number, min(imei) as imei1,
       case when count(*) > 1 then max(imei) end as imei2
from tablename
group by device_id, serial_number
```

Comment: Thanks @jarlh. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

`select device_id,serial_number,GROUP_CONCAT(imei) as imeis from devices group by device_id,serial_number;`

This is not an exact solution but may help you.
Other solution could be a self join but it is not possible on two fields simultaneously.